# After reformatting my laptop and installing Windows 10, some of my dialogs are enormous

Tags: sql-server, windows-10

Does anyone know which Windows 10 setting fixes this? Some of my dialogs are enormous, like in Sql Server Management Studio.

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing down votes. Please comment as to why - should I rephrase? Put the question on another SO sub domain? Not appropriate for SO at all? Constructive criticism is welcome please, thanks!

Comment: I've seen this happen when using DPI scaling. Go to Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Display. You should see a screen telling you to change the size of all items. Try adjusting those settings and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Paul. Unfortunately, each of those options has "9px" as the value, so it's not like any of them are bigger than the others. I'm starting to chalk this up to the fact that I have Sql Server Mgmt Studio 2012, which is an older software that doesn't play as well with Win10. I might try and get a newer version of the software. Thanks!

Comment: Ok @Ian Davis. Mine shows available percentages and adjusting it to above 125% causes the same issue you are seeing, but I am running 8.1. Perhaps Windows 10 has different options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing Sql Server Management Studio 2012, my 2014 version worked again. No more giant font sizes. Not sure why that did it, but all is well now. In case anyone else runs into this same issue.